# PayPal Button is not clickable link in Prestashop

Tags: php, paypal, smarty, prestashop

I have installed the PayPal module and added all of the API details. It appears on the page, however it cannot be clicked. Why could this be? The code, as viewed in the source, is this:

It looks a bit odd to me. Like the image should be linked to the form somehow?

Also tried it in sandbox mode and that doesn't work either.

```
<div id="HOOK_SHOPPING_CART_EXTRA">
    <div id="container_express_checkout" style="float:right; margin: 10px 40px 0 0">
        <img id="payment_paypal_express_checkout" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" alt="" />
        <form id="paypal_payment_form" action="http://mydomain.com/store/modules/paypal/express_checkout/payment.php" data-ajax="false" title="Pay with PayPal" method="post" data-ajax="false">
            <!-- Change dynamicaly when the form is submitted -->
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id_p_attr" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="express_checkout" value="cart"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="current_shop_url" value="http://mydomain.com/store/index.php?controller=order&multi-shipping=0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="FR_PRESTASHOP_H3S" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edit for ident your html code. Could be that you misssing a close tag </div>?

Comment: Wasn't the div, I just miscopied. I solved it and I've added the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself. The required code that makes the button work was missing the header. If anyone else finds this page in the future, the code you need is:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

$('#payment_paypal_express_checkout').click(function() {
    $('#paypal_payment_form').submit();
    return false;
});

$('#paypal_payment_form').live('submit', function() {
    var nb = $('#quantity_wanted').val();
    var id = $('#idCombination').val();

    $('#paypal_payment_form input[name=quantity]').val(nb);
    $('#paypal_payment_form input[name=id_p_attr]').val(id);
});

function displayExpressCheckoutShortcut() {
    var id_product = $('input[name="id_product"]').val();
    var id_product_attribute = $('input[name="id_product_attribute"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: baseDir+'/modules/paypal/express_checkout/ajax.php',
        data: { get_qty: "1", id_product: id_product, id_product_attribute: id_product_attribute },
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if (result >= '1')
                $('#container_express_checkout').slideDown();
            else
                $('#container_express_checkout').slideUp();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

$('select[name^="group_"]').change(function () {
    displayExpressCheckoutShortcut();
});

$('.color_pick').click(function () {
    displayExpressCheckoutShortcut();
});




var modulePath = 'modules/paypal';
var subFolder = '/integral_evolution';
var fullPath = baseDir + modulePath + subFolder;
var confirmTimer = false;

if ($('form[target="hss_iframe"]').length == 0) {
    if ($('select[name^="group_"]').length > 0)
        displayExpressCheckoutShortcut();
    return false;
} else {
    checkOrder();
}

function checkOrder() {
    confirmTimer = setInterval(getOrdersCount, 1000);
}

    function getOrdersCount() {
    $.get(
        fullPath + '/confirm.php',
        { id_cart: '7' },
        function (data) {
            if ((typeof(data) != 'undefined') && (data > 0)) {
                clearInterval(confirmTimer);
                window.location.replace(fullPath + '/submit.php?id_cart=7');
                $('p.payment_module, p.cart_navigation').hide();
            }
        }
    );
}
});
```